# If $\int_\Omega dP = 1$ and $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, $\int_\Omega f dP = 1$, show $\int_\Omega \lvert f \rvert dP < \infty$ or counter-example

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-integral

If $\int_\Omega dP = 1$ and $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, $\int_\Omega f dP = 1$, show $\int_\Omega \lvert f \rvert dP < \infty$ or show a counter-example.

Would an $f$ that creates a sinusoid with infinite amplitude be a valid counter example?

Comment: How do you even define the integral when the function is not integrable?

Comment: It could be locally lebesgue integrable.

Comment: @jake It's not Lebesgue measure, I think you are missing context?

Comment: In measure theory the existence and finiteness of $\int f dP$ implies that $\int |f|dP <\infty$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, is there a proof to that? Or an axiom? Can I see that anywhere in the Durrett probability textbook?